# Where can I find the instructions to install Syndesis in my local infrastructure?

Tags: syndesis

I'd like to try out Syndesis to create some integrations. I like the low code aspect of Syndesis but I can't find the instructions on how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the [quickstart](https://syndesis.io/quickstart/) documentation on Syndesis website or have a look at some of the [Syndesis quickstarts GitHub repository](https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis-quickstarts) that walks you through some of the example integrations.